# Timers or timed events for backbone.js Views

Tags: events, timer, backbone.js

I am trying to build an automatic carousel as a Backbone.js View so that it slides every so often.  Ideally what I would like is a timer event.  Something like

```
events{
  "timer 5000" : "slide"
}
```

I don't see this happening.  I tried firing the function from the outside.

```
window.setInterval(carouselView.slide, 5000);
```

That works.  BUT, I can't access the instance of the view anymore.  If i do a `console.log(this);` it gives me `Window`.  I guess this is because the function is being called from `Window` and not from the view instance.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question by now but you can do this without binding.

```
(function(view) {
  window.setInterval(function() { view.slide(); }, 5000);
})(this);
```

If you stick that in your view's initialize it should work. What it does is basically creating a closure so that you still have access to the view inside your setInterval block.

I do agree that a timer event like "timer 5000" : "slide" would have been a nice feature for Backbone as I googled my way here looking for something exactly like that.

Comment: Will this leak the view until the callback is removed?

Comment: I haven't tested that as we only ever created our views once but I would guess so. setInterval does return an ID though, which you could use with clearInterval when removing the view to avoid leaks.

Comment: Perfect, indeed that's what I ended up doing in my views once I'm done with the timed callback. Works as intended.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand what is meant by a 'closure'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the function to the context. I'm not 100% sure but I think this should work:

```
slide: _.bind(function(){ ... }, this)
```

See [Backbone FAQ](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this)

Comment: Thanks, but, it didn't fly.  Same issue that `this` is `Window`.

Comment: I prefer to use _.bind or _.bindAll in the view's initialize function: initialize: function(){ this._bindAll(this, 'slide'}; window.setInterval(this.slide, 5000); }

Comment: Ah, this should be better, as I'm mostly using coffee-script these days, I forgot about this.

Comment: What worked in the end was : `initialize : function() {_.bindAll(this, 'slide');`}